# Use of a List to instanciate

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a PowerPoint addin in C#, and everytime I open or create a new presentation, a panel is added.
I have a problem with instanciation of the panel
I can open several presentations at the same time, so I tried to make a List of panels like this:

```
 public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private UserControlA myControl1;
        private UserControlA myControl2;
        private UserControlA myControl3;
        private UserControlA myControl4;
        private UserControlA myControl5;
        private List<UserControlA> myControlX;

        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane1;  
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane2;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane3;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane4;
        private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane5;
        private List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> myCustomTaskPaneX;

        int iNbOfInstances = 0;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            myControl1 = new UserControlA();
            myControl2 = new UserControlA();
            myControl3 = new UserControlA();
            myControl4 = new UserControlA();
            myControl5 = new UserControlA();

            List<UserControlA> myControlX = new List<UserControlA> {
                myControl1, myControl2, myControl3, myControl4, myControl5
            };

            List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> myCustomTaskPaneX = new List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> {
                myCustomTaskPane1, myCustomTaskPane2, myCustomTaskPane3, myCustomTaskPane4, myCustomTaskPane5
            };

            // event for new presentation
            ((EApplication_Event)this.Application).NewPresentation +=
                new PowerPoint.EApplication_NewPresentationEventHandler(
                Application_NewPrez);

            // event for presnetation opening
            this.Application.PresentationOpen +=
                new PowerPoint.EApplication_PresentationOpenEventHandler(
                Application_NewPrez);
        }


        private void Application_NewPrez(PowerPoint.Presentation Prez)
        {
            if (iNbOfInstances >= 0 && iNbOfInstances <= 10)
            {

                myCustomTaskPaneX[iNbOfInstances] = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myControlX[iNbOfInstances], "Addin Name");
                DisplayPanel();

                iNbOfInstances++;
            }
        }

        private void DisplayPanel()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= iNbOfInstances; i++)
                myCustomTaskPaneX[iNbOfInstances].Visible = true;
        }
```

When I start PowerPoint I have an error at the line

```
myCustomTaskPaneX[iNbOfInstances] = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myControlX[iNbOfInstances], "Addin Name");
```

saying that reference is not defined as myControlX is null

Do you know what is the problem in my code ?
PS: I tried debugger, and when PowerPoint is launched, myControlX is not null, but as soon as I choose a presentation in the PowerPoint welcome page, then it becomes null.

Comment: When, exactly, does ThisAddIn_Startup() run?  Is it before, or after DisplayPanel()?

Comment: It is before (when you open PowerPoint, ThisAddIn_Startup() runs, then I go to the welcome page where I can select several templates - when I select a template, is event is called, and then Display method)

Comment: Ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
List<UserControlA> myControlX = new List<UserControlA> {
    myControl1, myControl2, myControl3, myControl4, myControl5
};

List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> myCustomTaskPaneX = new List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> {
    myCustomTaskPane1, myCustomTaskPane2, myCustomTaskPane3, myCustomTaskPane4, myCustomTaskPane5
};
```

To:

```
myControlX = new List<UserControlA> {
    myControl1, myControl2, myControl3, myControl4, myControl5
};

myCustomTaskPaneX = new List<Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane> {
            myCustomTaskPane1, myCustomTaskPane2, myCustomTaskPane3, myCustomTaskPane4, myCustomTaskPane5
};
```

So that way the scope of "myControlX" (and "myCustomTaskPaneX ") is class-level, not procedure-level.